# Asking for the user name and password for the localhost in firefox, after installing WAMP

Tags: iis, passwords, localhost, wamp

I have already running IIS in my windows XP. I have also install wamp server.

1. **The wamp server is showing the inactive icon.
2. When I was installing the WAMP, I was asked to set the firefox as my default browers for WAMP. Now when I am going to start use any service of it (i.e. localhost or phpmyadmin), firefox is asking me for the username & password for the same (the dialog box saying that **"Enter username and password for http: //localhost"**)

What should I do ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to turn of IIS by putting **inetmgr** in run, then you will get window for IIS by that you can turn off IIS.
Because IIS is run on port 80 and apache of WAMP is also trying to run on port 80,but that was acquired by IIS so you have to stop IIS.

And regarding firefox it is upto you ,that you have to put it default or not.

Comment: Thanks Sandip, I got success. Not exactly in the way you told but your suggestion was helpful to turn of IIS since it was only the issue. Thanks again.